# Have C library call python function with ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a DLL in c and meant for windows platforms which has a structure similar to the following:

**C Structure**

```
typedef struct some_struct {
    int (_stdcall *function)(int arg1, int arg2);
    ...
}SOME_STRUCT;
```

I've defined a python ctypes structure to mimic this with the following

**Python Structure**

```
class SOME_STRUCT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('function', POINTER(CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int))), ...]
```

The point of this structure in the C code is to register a callback function that gets executed upon certain triggers in its own thread. What I want to be able to do, if possible, is set that callback to be a Python function such that when the function in the C structure gets called from the C code, it is the python function that gets executed.

What I've got in python to try and accomplish this (which doesn't work) is the following:

```
def func(arg1,arg2):
    print('I was called!')
    return 0

struct = SOME_STRUCT()
prototype = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int)
struct.function = byref(prototype(func))
```

The specific error I get (that may not be my only issue) is that it complains that `struct.function` was expecting a `LP_CFunctionType` instance but got a `CArgObject` instance. How can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The example in the ctypes docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions doesn't use the call to `byref` as you are doing.  Does it work if you remove the byref call and just do `struct.function = prototype(func)`?

Comment: @PaulCornelius I tried doing that but the function never seems to get called then. I never see an output from it. I was trying to follow the example you pointed out, but I believe I need `byref` or something similar since I'm trying to assign a pointer to a function rather than a function itself (which the example is doing).

Comment: In that case I have one more thought.  If CFUNCTYPE returns an object that represents a pointer to a function, maybe you don't want the POINTER() function call in your structure definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example and test DLL source.  Oddly, I couldn't get it to work when the callback was the only member of the struct (crash).  It seemed like a bug, because a callback without a struct wrapper or adding a second member to the struct made it work.

Things to note:

- Use `WINFUNCTYPE` with `__stdcall`.  `CFUNCTYPE` is for `__cdecl`.
- You don't need `POINTER` or `byref` to make it work.
- The `@CALLBACK` decorator is equivalent to `func = CALLBACK(func)`.

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (__stdcall *CALLBACK)(int arg1, int arg2);

typedef struct some_struct {
    CALLBACK function;
    int other;
} SOME_STRUCT;

__declspec(dllexport) int func(SOME_STRUCT* pss)
{
    printf("%d\n",pss->other);
    return pss->function(1,2);
}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *

CALLBACK = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int,c_int,c_int)

class SOME_STRUCT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('function', CALLBACK),
                ('other', c_int)]

@CALLBACK
def callback(arg1,arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2

dll = CDLL('test')
dll.argtypes = POINTER(SOME_STRUCT),
dll.restype = c_int

struct = SOME_STRUCT(callback,7)
print(dll.func(byref(struct)))
```

**Output**

```
7
3
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This has been very useful. One minor thing though, I had to do `dll.func(byref(struct))` (last line of test.py) to make the call work.

Comment: @zephyr It worked without it for me but that is more technically correct.  Did you have the final comma in `argtypes`?  It must be a sequence and that makes it a tuple.

Comment: Yes, I did. In fact I copied and pasted your two programs and they worked just fine with the exception of the need for the byref. Without it, I get an OSError saying an access violation when writing to some random memory address.

Comment: @zephyr 32-bit or 64-bit Python?  I'm just wondering why it worked for me and looking for the difference. I was using 64-bit and am guessing the marshaling of a struct is always by pointer in that ABI.  It might also explain why I crashed when there was only one structure member. I'll have to go back and try that fix.

Comment: I'm using 32-bit.